# elasticsearch cluster stats indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running standalone ElasticSearch/Kibana servers for multiple tenants. I would like to  pull the cluster stats from each single instance and would like to import them into my own ElasticSearch/Kibana. How would I go about doing this? I have started to export the cluster stats to a file already.

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/stats?human&pretty' > tenant01.json

I then transfer the tenant01.json file to my own ElasticSearch/Kibana. How would I start to import the data into a new index?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bulk API into the new index

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/newIndex/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

Follow the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) for the correct file format, notice it uses \n to separate metadata from source values,so it needs not to be pretty printed

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```